# Is there a built in function to escape string for Oracle query? (like mysql_real_escape_string for MySQL)

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I understand that the proper way to handle all SQL query nowadays should be using PDO (or use the function provided in a PHP framework, like eloquent in laravel) However, as there is `mysql_real_escape_string` for MySQL, I am curious if there is a function like that for Oracle in PHP?

I have searched on Google and most answer seems to be writing a string replace code by yourself. That works at least on some common problem like quote (`'`), but I am just curious if there are built-in function for that. (and just in case there are other escape needed to be done to prevent SQL injection)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? There's [a complete Oracle extension](http://php.net/oci8), officially endorsed by Oracle, will full prepared statements support.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your real question about SQL injection you should (in fact 'must') use bind variables instead of string concatenation, as mentioned by [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez).  This is also important for performance and scalability.  Binding keeps the data separate from the SQL, and avoids the strict need to sanitize data.  To use an example I have laying around:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/orclpdb');

$query = "select first_name, last_name
          from employees
          order by
              case :ob
                   when 'FIRST_NAME' then first_name
                   else last_name
              end";

$vs = "FIRST_NAME";

$s = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":ob", $vs);
$r = oci_execute($s);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "  <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES):"&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package DBMS_ASSERT. It is dedicate to prepare and validate input string. [DBMS_ASSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABJDIJE)
`ENQUOTE_LITERAL` function

If want to hardcore string literals you can use quitting mechanism.
`q'(  ... )'`
`q'~ ... ~'`
`q'! ... !'`

```
DECLARE
       v VARCHAR2(1024);
    BEGIN
       v := q'( The string  with quouts ',','   )';
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v);
    END;
```

Comment: This will add extra round-trips to the application which will impact scalability.  It's better to use bind variables so that the SQL and data are separate.